# using alert from JavaScript (D3r) to pass data to R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs, htmlwidgets

I need to pass data from Sunburst plot to R (server side). The following code creates a sunburst plot and gives alert on the level that you select (curtesy of Kerry and his great work with HTMLWidgets and SunburstR). I would like to be able to pass that information on so that I can create a download list.

```
library(sunburstR)

# read in sample visit-sequences.csv data provided in source
#   https://gist.github.com/kerryrodden/7090426#file-visit-sequences-csv
sequences <- read.csv(
  system.file("examples/visit-sequences.csv",package="sunburstR")
  ,header = FALSE
  ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

sb <- sunburst(sequences)

sb$x$tasks <- list(
  htmlwidgets::JS(
"
function(){
  //debugger;

  this.instance.chart.on('click',function(d){
    alert(d);
  });
}
"    
  )
)

sb
```

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
this.instance.chart.on('click',function(d){
    Shiny.onInputChange("val", d);
});
```

then you can use

```
input$val
```

on server side which gives you the value d.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I had been banging my head for two days on it.